# Bash script to run several files successively

Tags: bash, shell

I'm learning flex and bison and bash.

I created an .exe called `compiler`

I have a bunch of .txt files to test repeatedly.

How can I write a script that would run:

```
./compiler test1.txt
./compiler test2.txt
...etc
```

I don't want to pass them all at once as arguments.  Just run them successively.

I wrote `script.sh` in the same directory I'm working with the compiler and test files:

```
#!/bin/bash

clear
./compiler test9.txt
./compiler test8.txt
./compiler test7.txt
./compiler test6.txt
./compiler test5.txt
./compiler test4.txt
./compiler test3.txt
./compiler test2.txt
./compiler text1.txt
```

Then I did `chmod u+x script.sh`
and tried `script.sh`

Didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure `bash` is in `/bin`? What's the result of `type bash`? Also, does `bash script.sh` work?

Comment: What does happen when you run it?

Comment: @AndrewBarber:  it just said command not found.  Etan Reisner's answer worked though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `./script.sh` to run a file from the current directory (the same way you have it for `./compiler`).

That being said that script should work fine for what it does.

But you can do the same thing with a loop as well:

```
for file in test*.txt; do
    ./compiler "$file"
done
```

Comment: I would prefer `find . -name "test*.txt" -exec ./compiler {} \;`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Valid but may do significant amounts of extra work (in case there are sub-directories around) for the specific task at hand.

Comment: There's certainly more then one way to do it.

Comment: Thank you!  Worked perfectly (except for my text.txt typo :)  I didn't realize the `./` was for running the file from the current directory.  Baby steps.  And a loop too.  Who 'da thunk it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Your preference above, that's a script or a command?  Can you talk me through the individual parts?

Comment: @MayNotBe That's an example of the find command. It will find every file that starts with "test" and ends with ".txt" and pass that file to the `./compiler` command. You can limit the depth of directories to search with `-maxdepth`

Comment: A shell "script" is just a series of commands. His preference is to use the `find` command (which is a great command to know but a bit hard to learn) rather than the shell loop.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch any particular reason you would prefer the `find` approach to (what appears to me to be) a simpler `for` loop?

Comment: @kojiro It can process files in sub-folders, it can also handle a few edge cases better (like white space without quotes, and of course if your file happens to have quotes in the name).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch hmm. I don't dispute the sub-folder thing (although many shells have recursive globbing now, too), but as for the other thing: using find is a lot of work just to avoid putting quotes around an expansion! (The shell would not have any problem with whitespace, quotes, or other characters in an expansion if the name is properly quoted.)

Comment: @kojiro And if your filename contains `"` and `'` characters? Like `"Alice's Adventures in Wonderland" - "Carrol, Lewis".epub` (as an example)?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch [The shell handles it fine.](https://gist.github.com/kojiromike/dc9c914194a4c234446e) Granted, you have to jump through some hoops to manually _create_ such an unwieldy filename, but once created, handling it with a glob is not a problem.

Comment: @kojiro I note you did not use the for loop above and you had to use `printf`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I didn't _have_ to use `printf`. Its only there to improve the clarity of the post for human readers. I'm not sure what you mean about the for loop: I couldn't recreate it much more precisely since the glob above wouldn't match the filename you specified and I don't have a compile script in my working directory.

Comment: To restate what has already been said the for loop in my answer handles filenames with whatever special characters they might have in them perfectly correctly. The glob expansion does not get word split or unquoted in any way. And quoting the variable expansion in the loop body likewise protects the variable's contents from mangling by the shell. There is no reason to use `find` to ensure correct processing of these sorts of files (and in fact many people who use find do so in a way that *cannot* handle such filenames correctly).